# Paginating DynamoDB using numbers and query parameters

Tags: node.js, express, pagination, amazon-dynamodb

I am building a web application using the express npm library for node.js. I am pulling data from an AWS DynamoDB which has a lot of Items. I want my web app to paginate this data by calling /query/:number. So I can go to /query/10 for the first 10 Items, and then /query/20 for the next 10 results?

I know I can paginate by passing the LastEvaluatedKey to ExclusiveStartKey but I want to know if there is a better way.

Thanks!